# MVC controller, take parameters in as class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am using jquery to POST data via ajax, and in chrome tools it is showing the data being sent like this:

```
PermssionArray[0][Permitted]:false
PermssionArray[0][Id]:2
PermssionArray[1][Permitted]:true
PermssionArray[1][Id]:3
PermssionArray[2][Permitted]:true
PermssionArray[2][Id]:4
```

My controller is like this:

```
  public ActionResult UpdatePermissions(PermSet[] PermssionArray)
```

And my PermSet class is like this:

```
  public class PermSet
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public bool Permitted { get; set; }
        }
```

If I breakpoint in the controller, is has 3 items in the PermssionArray array, but the values are all id = 0, permitted = false.

What do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: You have to go for custom model binding or fetch data from FormCollection.

Answer (score 5):

Lists are really odd in ASP.Net MVC, and you have options to get your data to the server.

1. Use the default model binding in ASP.NET MVC. This requires you change your model to post back with a certain format. Check out Phil Haack's post on this. This works but can get hairy if you have a lot of lists.  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx
2. Second option is to use jQuery to circumvent your post and serialize your form into a JSON document, then POST that to the server. Option 2 is much easier, but requires you handle ajax requests rather than direct POST / Redirect actions.

   - use JSON.stringify(model)
   - return a response that includes the next page to redirect to on a success
   - return a response that includes any error message

I will assume you know how to use jQuery and the $.ajax method.

I started leaning more towards option two when the page's complexity starts getting larger. The only downside is you need a really good client story. Consider using knockout.js as it let's you convert your form to JSON using ko.toJSON.

Let me know if you would like me to go into detail on anything.